# avoid daemon running in dedicated cpu cores

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have grub set isolcpus=2 in my linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 , what I want is 
avoid the kernel scheduler not to schedule task to cpu core 2 , then I have the

```
perf  record -e  sched:sched_switch -C 2
```

to see what is going on in core 2 and then run my ap(which CPU_SET(2) ,
and  following command :

```
perf report --show-total-period -i perf.data
```

get result :

```
  48.85%            85  swapper         [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
  18.97%            33  kworker/u384:0  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
  11.49%            20  :4594           [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
  11.49%            20  smartd          [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
   4.60%             8  watchdog/2      [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
   3.45%             6  sshd            [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
   1.15%             2  kworker/2:2     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __schedule
```

I know kworker/2 , watchdog/2  are housekeeping tasks , thread id 4594 is what I run my app with CPU_SET(2)  , But I really do want to avoid sshd , smartd daemons running in core 2 , Is there any config file or methods I can do to tell kernel that avoid daemons running in core 2 ?!

Edit :

after edit grub , there should be update-grub command and then reboot ,
I will try to figure out how to update-grub , I think grub config isolcpus=2 but it is not enabled yet , I will update the result after I make isolcpus=2 work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program 'schedtool' maybe helpful, it can limit the process to run on specified cpu(s).
according to the help of that utility.
 To set a process' affinity to only the first CPU (CPU0):
 #> schedtool -a 0x1 
replace the parameters 0x1 and PID  according your exactly requirement.