# How to (is it possible to) avoid kworker and watchdog to run on specified core

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, cpu-usage, watchdog

I am trying to minimize the usage some cores of my CPUs. *(FYI I have an Intel Core i7-4790, 4 cores with hyperthreading, so 8 logical cores)*

I see that I have a *watchdog* thread (or process) and a *kworker* thread (or process) running on each one of my logical cores

I would like them **not to run** on logical cores 3 and 7.

Do you know if this is possible and, if so, how can I do it. I would appreciate any relevant documentation on this subject

> One more thing, watchdog and kworker are both running on my cores 3
>   and 7 even though they are isolated via the kernel option `isolcpus`

Regards

> *FYI, This question is the continuation of another one I recently*
>   *posted: [Cannot avoid context-switches on a process launched alone on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774217/cannot-avoid-context-switches-on-a-process-launched-alone-on-a-cpu)*
>   *a CPU*

Comment: Both `kworker` and `watchdog`  are probably not CPU intensive (and are probably mostly idle or waiting for some event, input or interrupt) so it should not matter

Comment: I do agree, they are absolutely not CPU intensive. However, in the purpose of a previous question I posted, regarding context switch  ([Cannot avoid context-switches on a process launched alone on a CPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774217/cannot-avoid-context-switches-on-a-process-launched-alone-on-a-cpu)) I really would like to be able to disable it on some specific cores

Answer (score 1):

I found that watchdog can be disabled by providing the option `nowatchdog` to the Linux Kernel.